# THREE.js 1 Renderer 2 Viewports:- Incorrect Scaling

Tags: javascript, three.js

See [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9wkruo15/1/)

I have one scene and two cameras.
Each camera is mapped to a viewport and the two viewports sit side by side on the same renderer object.

### Edit: Problem 1 is solved as per comment by /u/gaitat/ and jsfiddle updated.

Problem 1: The width of the 2nd viewport is twice that of the first viewport.
Here is the rendering code.

```
function render() { 

//... clear entire renderer
renderer.setViewport
    (0             , 0, 
     renderer_width, renderer_height);
renderer.clear();

//... 1st viewport (left)
renderer.setViewport
    (0                   , 0, 
     renderer_width * 0.5, renderer_height);   
renderer.render(scene, camera1);

renderer.clearDepth(); //... seems to have no effect in this case (no VP overlap)

//... 2nd viewport (right)
renderer.setViewport
   (renderer_width * 0.5, 0, 
    renderer_width      , renderer_height);
renderer.render(scene, camera2);

}
```

(Problem 2: has been moved to another question).

Comment: for your 1st problem use: `renderer.setViewport(renderer_width * 0.5, 0,         renderer_width * 0.5, renderer_height);` for your second viewport.

Comment: @gaitat.  Oh yes, of course, I was thinking setViewport paramters were (width_start, height_start, width_end, height_end) whereas in fact it is (width_start, height_start, width, height). I should have read the manual!  Many thanks.